# Selenium login process automate to Grofers - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate the process for logging into [Grofers](https://grofers.com/) - an Indian eCommerce grocery market.
My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
time.sleep(1)

driver.get('https://grofers.com/')
time.sleep(3)

login = driver.find_element_by_class_name('account-wrapper')
login.click()
time.sleep(3)

mobileNo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="phone-no-text-box"]')
mobileNo.send_keys('<Phone Number>')
time.sleep(3)

cont = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-next-button"]')
cont.click()
```

When I run this script, I get the this error:

```
elenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <div class="account-wrapper"> 
is not clickable at point (1136,57) because another element <div class="location__overlay"> obscures it
```

Couldn't get past it. Can anybody help?

**Edit**: I solved this issue. If anyone is facing the same problem, they can let me know, I'll share my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The location selector on the page requires you to select a location before it closes.

Adding this code after the first time.sleep(3) should solve the problem, it just finds and selects the default location, Gurugram.

```python
locationSelecter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]")
locationSelecter.click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: It is giving the error: ```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]```